# Slider slides many times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a slider with event listeners `touchstart` and `touchmove`.

The slider works very good, if you click on the buttons. But if you move your finger from left to right, it slides many times until the last image but it should only slide once. Also you cannot slide back.

```
var i = 0;

// Go next
$('.next').bind('click', function() {           
    niceSlider('left', '<');
});

// Go Back
$('.back').bind('click', function() {
    niceSlider('right', '>', 0); 
});

// Greather or less
function greatherOrLess(num1, operator, num2) {
    if (operator == '<') {
    return (num1 < num2) ? true : false;
  }
  else if (operator == '>') {
    return (num1 > num2) ? true : false;
  }
}

// Slider
function niceSlider(direction, operator, NumberOfAllImages = 4, position = 600) {
  var direction = (direction == 'left') ? '-' : '+';  
  if (greatherOrLess(i, operator, NumberOfAllImages)) {
    if (direction == '+' || direction == '-') {
      $('li').animate({'left': direction + '=600px'}, 300).delay(600);  
      x = (direction == '-') ? i++ : i--;
    }
  }
  console.log($('li:first').position().left);
  console.log(x);   
}

// Event Listener
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
slider.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);
slider.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);

// Start from touch
function handleTouchStart(evt) {
  startClientX = evt.touches[0].clientX;
  startClientY = evt.touches[0].clientY;
}

// Move from touch
function handleTouchMove(evt) {
  moveClientX = evt.touches[0].clientX;
  moveClientY = evt.touches[0].clientY;

  var diffClientX = startClientX - moveClientX;
  var diffClientY = startClientY - moveClientY;

  if (Math.abs(diffClientX) > Math.abs(diffClientY)) {
    if (diffClientX > 0) {
      niceSlider('left', '<');
    }
    else {
      niceSlider('right', '>');
    }
  }
}
```

There must be something wrong with the function `handleTouchMove`. How can I fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/6t1wx95f/16/

Comment: Every movement will cause it to move in that direction... You're moving a LOT with one swipe. You could use a boolean like `currentlyMoving=true` to make it stop handling the touch while it's already in handleTouchMove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function handleTouchStart(evt) {
  startClientX = evt.touches[0].clientX;
  startClientY = evt.touches[0].clientY;
  checkTouch = true;
}

// Move from touch
function handleTouchMove(evt) {
  moveClientX = evt.touches[0].clientX;
  moveClientY = evt.touches[0].clientY;

  if (checkTouch) {
    var diffClientX = startClientX - moveClientX;
    var diffClientY = startClientY - moveClientY;
    if (Math.abs(diffClientX) > Math.abs(diffClientY)) {
      if (diffClientX > 0) {
        niceSlider('left', '<');
      } else {
        niceSlider('right', '>', 0);
      }
    }
    checkTouch = false;
  }
}

function handleTouchEnd(evt) {
  checkTouch = true;
}
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/6t1wx95f/18/), check it for only once use a boolean value. On touch move next function was calling on every move.